# Transform a constrained tuple type

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```js
interface Box<T = unknown> {
  value: T;
}

type Unboxed<T extends Box[]> = T extends [infer U, ...infer V] ? [U["value"], ...Unboxed<V>] : [];
```

It generates two errors:

- `U["value"]`: `Type '"value"' cannot be used to index type 'U'.`
- `Unboxed<V>`: `Type 'V' does not satisfy the constraint 'Box<unknown>[]'.`

Why is `infer U` not picking up the `Box`-constraint?

Comment: Might I suggest using a mapped type instead https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeAeAKsgXmQFcQBrEdAdxAD5kBvAKGWQDc4AbYiALmVwBuJgF8mTMAE8ADigCqIAEZYIAEzzIImSCFUBnNFgDaAXXpFmrVkYAKyUMjIRJ6GAJP8AFLlsnkAMkMcUgpqOgBKIwByDm4IKJNRcSlZZAANQmQFZUw1bCMMHBBiAFtFaFoAGiDsPTAoUABzWjMgA

Comment: Actually, the tuple I am passing is branded (via a `__brand: unique symbol`) and that breaks the mapping.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I now brand the tuple elements instead of branding the tuple itself.